# conflict between headline and sidebar beamer

Tags: header, latex, sidebar, beamer

I'm trying to create a beamer template, but I have a problem to have my sidebar at the height of the slide.

Indeed, my headline (taken from [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=588) and personalized later) cuts the top of the slide.

[image]

I tried adding a \makebox to the headline, adding \setbeamersize{headline=0.5\textwidth} to reduce the size, but nothing made it.

here is the code (a litle simplified)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}


% Tikz package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,shadows}


\newenvironment{frameMain}[1]
{
%title placement
\renewcommand{\frametitle}[1]{
    \section{##1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \node[anchor=west, text=black, font=\Huge\selectfont] at ([xshift=30px]current page.west) {
          
            \scaleto{\MakeUppercase{##1}}{1.3em}};
          
    \end{tikzpicture}}

    
    \begin{frame}
    
        \frametitle{#1}}
{
    
    \end{frame}
}


\newenvironment{myframe}[1]
{
    \let\oldframetitle\frametitle
    \renewcommand{\frametitle}[1]{
        \subsection{##1}
        \oldframetitle{##1}
    }
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[ align=right, anchor=south east, text=black, font=\selectfont] at ([xshift=0px, yshift=1em]current page.south east) {
                   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
              };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \frametitle{#1}}
{
    
    \end{frame}
}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% headline from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=588
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtotcounter{mysec}
\AtBeginSection{\addtocounter{mysec}{1}\label{mysec:\themysec}}
\newcounter{foo}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \vskip6pt
    %\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[draw=gray,rounded corners,preaction={fill, lightgray},pattern={Lines[angle=45,line width=3pt,distance=6pt]},pattern color=lightgray!50] (0,0) rectangle (.8\paperwidth,0.3);
        \path[rounded corners,preaction={fill, green!50!teal},pattern={Lines[angle=45,line width=3pt,distance=6pt]},pattern color=green!50!teal!50] (0,0) rectangle ({(\thepage-1)/(\insertdocumentendpage-1)*.8\paperwidth},0.3);
        \ifnum\thesection>0
            \path[rounded corners,preaction={fill, cyan!50!blue},pattern={Lines[angle=45,line width=3pt,distance=6pt]},pattern color=cyan!50!blue!50] (0,0) rectangle ({(\insertsectionstartpage-1)/(\insertdocumentendpage-1)*.8\paperwidth},0.3);
        \fi
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\totvalue{mysec}}{%
            \setcounterpageref{foo}{mysec:\x}
            \colorlet{seccol}{green!50!teal}
            \ifnum\thesection=\x
                \colorlet{seccol}{green!50!teal}
            \else
                \ifnum\thesection<\x
                    \colorlet{seccol}{lightgray}
                \else
                    \colorlet{seccol}{cyan!50!blue}
                \fi
            \fi     
            \node[circle,fill=seccol,draw=white,line width=1.5pt,minimum size=15pt] at ({(\thefoo-1)/(\insertdocumentendpage-1)*.8\paperwidth},0.15) {\x};
            \node[seccol] at ({(\thefoo-1)/(\insertdocumentendpage-1)*.8\paperwidth},-0.35) {\nameref{mysec:\x}};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    %\par%
}
%\end{comment}

%%%%%%%%%
%sidebar%
%%%%%%%%%

\useoutertheme[right,width=35px,height=0cm]{sidebar}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{%
    bg=brown
    }





\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\begin{frame}{}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{sub title}
    \author{Author}
    \date{date}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Summary}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}  


\section{title2}
\begin{frame}{}
    \frametitle{title2}
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubTitle}
\begin{frame}{SubTitle}
    \begin{block}{normal bloc}
        normal bloc text
    \end{block}

    \begin{alertblock}{alert block}
        alert bloc text
    \end{alertblock}

    \begin{exampleblock}{example block}
        example block text
    \end{exampleblock}

    \begin{proof}
        a proof
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS: Logically no more compilation errors (sorry again for this)

Comment: Your code does  not compile. Please test it before posting a question.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought to give the idea with the simplified code, it's fixed and it's compilable now.

Comment: Still does not compile for me: `Arithmetic overflow. \end{frameMain}`

Comment: .... (probably) unrelated, but hiding frame environments in other environments is basically  a guarantee for problems. You'll have a lot of fun with that as soon as you add fragile content to your frames.

Comment: ah yes, since I use overleaf, it does not bother me with this error (Arithmetic overflow)
(I'm changing this right now)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the same technique as the sidebar theme and place a coloured box above the sidebar:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}


% Tikz package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage{scalerel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}



\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,shadows}


\newenvironment{frameMain}[1]
{
%title placement
\renewcommand{\frametitle}[1]{
    \section{##1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
          \node[anchor=west, text=black, font=\Huge\selectfont] at ([xshift=30px]current page.west) {
          
            \scaleto{\MakeUppercase{##1}}{1.3em}};
          
    \end{tikzpicture}}

    
    \begin{frame}
    
        \frametitle{#1}}
{
    
    \end{frame}
}


\newenvironment{myframe}[1]
{
    \let\oldframetitle\frametitle
    \renewcommand{\frametitle}[1]{
        \subsection{##1}
        \oldframetitle{##1}
    }
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \node[ align=right, anchor=south east, text=black, font=\selectfont] at ([xshift=0px, yshift=1em]current page.south east) {
                   \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber
              };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \frametitle{#1}}
{
    
    \end{frame}
}




%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% headline from https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=588
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtotcounter{mysec}
\AtBeginSection{\addtocounter{mysec}{1}\label{mysec:\themysec}}
\newcounter{foo}



%\end{comment}

%%%%%%%%%
%sidebar%
%%%%%%%%%

\useoutertheme[right,width=35px,height=0cm]{sidebar}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\paperwidth-\beamer@sidebarwidth]{%
    \vspace{6pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path[draw=gray,rounded corners,preaction={fill, lightgray},pattern={Lines[angle=45,line width=3pt,distance=6pt]},pattern color=lightgray!50] (0,0) rectangle (.8\paperwidth,0.3);
        \path[rounded corners,preaction={fill, green!50!teal},pattern={Lines[angle=45,line width=3pt,distance=6pt]},pattern color=green!50!teal!50] (0,0) rectangle ({(\thepage-1)/(\insertdocumentendpage-1)*.8\paperwidth},0.3);
        \ifnum\thesection>0
            \path[rounded corners,preaction={fill, cyan!50!blue},pattern={Lines[angle=45,line width=3pt,distance=6pt]},pattern color=cyan!50!blue!50] (0,0) rectangle ({(\insertsectionstartpage-1)/(\insertdocumentendpage-1)*.8\paperwidth},0.3);
        \fi
        \foreach \x in {1,...,\totvalue{mysec}}{%
            \setcounterpageref{foo}{mysec:\x}
            \colorlet{seccol}{green!50!teal}
            \ifnum\thesection=\x
                \colorlet{seccol}{green!50!teal}
            \else
                \ifnum\thesection<\x
                    \colorlet{seccol}{lightgray}
                \else
                    \colorlet{seccol}{cyan!50!blue}
                \fi
            \fi     
            \node[circle,fill=seccol,draw=white,line width=1.5pt,minimum size=15pt] at ({(\thefoo-1)/(\insertdocumentendpage-1)*.8\paperwidth},0.15) {\x};
            \node[seccol] at ({(\thefoo-1)/(\insertdocumentendpage-1)*.8\paperwidth},-0.35) {\nameref{mysec:\x}};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{sidebar}\rule{\beamer@sidebarwidth}{\headheight}%
    %\par%
}
\makeatother

\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar right}{\vskip-\headheight}{}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=brown}



\begin{document}

\section{Title}
\begin{frame}{}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{sub title}
    \author{Author}
    \date{date}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Summary}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}  


\section{title2}
\begin{frame}{}
    \frametitle{title2}
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubTitle}
\begin{frame}{SubTitle}
    \begin{block}{normal bloc}
        normal bloc text
    \end{block}

    \begin{alertblock}{alert block}
        alert bloc text
    \end{alertblock}

    \begin{exampleblock}{example block}
        example block text
    \end{exampleblock}

    \begin{proof}
        a proof
    \end{proof}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]